# Dropping Series stored in Variable from a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Here is a simple problem but I'm unable to find a solution using either `pd.drop()` or `pd.difference()`. I need to return a new dataframe, excluding the selected series object, where the series object is stored in a variable during a for-loop. For instance: `val = df1[i]` and therefore need a solution like `df1.drop(val)`

```py
Df1:
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10    
 C  C  C  C  C  C  T  T  T  T        
 G  N  D  A  G  N  D  A  G  N       
 K  M  I  L  R  K  M  I  L  R       
 C  C  L  C  C  C  T  T  T  T      
 G  N  D  A  E  N  D  A  G  N        
 Y  F  V  H  Q  E  P  W  Y  F        
 G  N  D  A  G  N  F  A  G  G        
 G  Y  D  A  G  N  D  A  G  N        

Val:
2
C
N
M
C
N
F
N
Y

New Df1:
1  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10    
 C  C  C  C  C  T  T  T  T        
 G  D  A  G  N  D  A  G  N       
 K  I  L  R  K  M  I  L  R       
 C  L  C  C  C  T  T  T  T      
 G  D  A  E  N  D  A  G  N        
 Y  V  H  Q  E  P  W  Y  F        
 G  D  A  G  N  F  A  G  G        
 G  D  A  G  N  D  A  G  N
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the question, you talk in the general term of series. However, in the sample, you use a `df1` columnn as the excluded series. The solution is different for each case.

In case you use a column of `df1` as an excluded series, you may use `drop` using `series.name`. Since you slice a single column to a series, its name is the column name.

```
val = df1[2]
df_new = df1.drop(val.name, 1)

Out[222]:
  1  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
0  C  C  C  C  C  T  T  T  T
1  G  D  A  G  N  D  A  G  N
2  K  I  L  R  K  M  I  L  R
3  C  L  C  C  C  T  T  T  T
4  G  D  A  E  N  D  A  G  N
5  Y  V  H  Q  E  P  W  Y  F
6  G  D  A  G  N  F  A  G  G
7  G  D  A  G  N  D  A  G  N
```

---

If you use an independent series to exclude a column of `df1`, you can't use `series.name` because the `name` is now not column `name`. You need `eq` and `all` to check the series values to match the column values and slice with `loc`

```
val = pd.Series(['C', 'N', 'M', 'C', 'N', 'F', 'N', 'Y'])
df_new = df1.loc[:, ~df1.eq(val, axis=0).all()]

####Or

df_new = df1.drop(df1.eq(s, axis=0).all().idxmax(), 1)

Out[239]:
  1  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
0  C  C  C  C  C  T  T  T  T
1  G  D  A  G  N  D  A  G  N
2  K  I  L  R  K  M  I  L  R
3  C  L  C  C  C  T  T  T  T
4  G  D  A  E  N  D  A  G  N
5  Y  V  H  Q  E  P  W  Y  F
6  G  D  A  G  N  F  A  G  G
7  G  D  A  G  N  D  A  G  N
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
print(df1.drop(val.columns, axis=1))
```